# Eye pupil corner detection (openCV)

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, video-processing

I am trying to make a program in openCV (python) that can tell when an eye pupil is straight or at corners (left or right). What I have done so far is:

1. Took an image, cropped the eye part (detected the region through eye_cascade.detectMultiScale(gray)) (picture is attached).
2. Got BGR value ofpixel of img[(3*h)/4,w/2] (h=height, w=width)
3. Tried to mask the skin by converting BRG to HSV, did thresh_BINARY to get only remaining white shade of around pupil.
4. count white pixels and checked if either side has less than 40% of white pixels then decide the position of pupil.

This method gives somewhat good answer for picture but when I start the webcam, masking fails thus failing further entire process.
Anyone has better idea on how I can do this? (Already read all the answered questions on this forum but couldn't find a satisfactory solution).

Image

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I think it is because binary thresholding outputs pixels greater than Scalar 127 as white and the remaining as black. This gives really bad results in dark ( where most pixels are less than 127 ) and light ( where most pixels have more than 127 value).

What you can do is to find the mean and standard deviation.
Then you can define a mask in such a way that all pixels above
        mean+k*std_deviation 

 as white pixels. You can find the constant k by experimenting with various images.

Good Luck!